# Can't run checksetup.pl for BugZilla requires ppm install DBI

Tags: perl, bugzilla

I'm following the installation guide for BugZilla at https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Win32Install.

I'm trying to install BugZilla on my Windows 2008 server.  I've installed Perl 4.17, Apache for windows 2.2.25 and BugZilla 4.4.1.  I'm at the point of running the command

```
C:\bugzilla>perl checksetup.pl
```

But when I run this command I get

[image]

I've then tried to install the package using

> ppm install DBI

but I get the message saying "No missing packages to install"

Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed a work around by commenting out the version check.  It appears that this is a bug 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=938300

Comment: Commented out the version check in checksetup.pl? I'm new to perl and would appreciate it if you'd tell me which file did you comment out the version check. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For me the main issue was that it thinks 1.614 is more than 1.63

In the console output, in red:

`Checking for                  DBI (v1.614)    found v1.63`

I changed Requirements.pm by requiring 1.63 for the said module. Thanks @Tommo1977

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem on Windows Server 2012 using Bugzilla 4.4.1 and ActivePerl 5.16.3.1603.

**Solved by removing one of the two DBI packages using ppm UI.** Just type 'ppm' in command line and then remove one DBI package.

Answer (score 0):

The version checking for DBI can be commented out in C:\Bugzilla\Bugzilla\Install\Requirements.pm

```
#{
#    package => 'DBI',
#    module  => 'DBI',
#    version => (vers_cmp($perl_ver, '5.13.3') > -1) ? '1.614' : '1.41'
#},
```